# Fixed Relationship Cartesian Product in Python

Tags: python, cartesian-product

Background:
I have interest in studying quantum phase transitions of various materials by writing simulations on DWave's Adiabatic Quantum Computer. To make it easier to produce phase plots as a function of parameters, I am writing utilities to sweep through the parameters, run the simulations with these parameter sets, and collect the data.

Background on Input Conditions:
On the DWave, there are two sets of parameters I can set, `h` biases and `J` couplings. These are inputted as follows: `h = {qubit0: hvalue0, qubit1: hvalue1,...}` and`J = {(qubit0, qubit1): J01, (qubit2, qubit3): J23, ...}`. So far, I have a tool that does a parameter sweep given inputs like this: `{qubit: [hz1, hz2,..., hzn]}` mapping qubits to `h` values to sweep and `{coupler: [J1, J2,..., Jn]}` mapping couplers to `J` values to sweep. In both cases, the output is a list of the form `[{trial1}, {trial2}, ... {trialn}]` that represents the cartesian product of the `h` and `J` inputs on each separate qubit and coupling.

What I Actually Want and What I've Written So Far:
In the above, I run into a serious problem. Suppose I want to sweep through a series of parameters where some qubits or couplers have a fixed relationship with respect to each other on any given run. This is important due to some complications where a logical problem must be mapped onto the DWave in non-trivial ways. For example, suppose I want to run a problem where `qubit0` has `h` in `[0, 1, 2]`, `qubit1` has `h` in `[1, 2, 3]` and `qubit3` has `h` in `[5, 8]`, BUT the relationship `qubit1_h = qubit0_h + 1` must be preserved; ie, I want the product of values to be `[(0, 1, 5), (0, 1, 8), (1, 2, 5), (1, 2, 8), ...]` and NOT all combinations as is given by a cartesian product.

The following code will do this for the h parameters, but does not work for the J parameters because the dictionary keys are tuples. Plus,I have to run my original code to generate the caretesian product if I don't want this functionality, so it seems to generate "3 cases."

```
def fixed_relationship_sweep(input_params, together):
    """
    Inputs
    ------
    input_params: {0:[x1, x2], 1:[x3, x4], 2:[y1, y2], 3:[y3, y4]]}
    dictionary mapping qubits to parameter lists to iterate through
    together: [[0, 1], [2, 3]]
    list of qubit lists that specify which qubit parameters to sweep with a fixed relationship

    Output
    ------
    fixed_rel_sweep: [{trial1}, {trial2}, ...{trialn}] where qubits labelled as "together" are
    swept with fixed 1-1 relationship, ie, above produces:
    [{0:x1, 1:x3, 2:y1, 3:y3}, {0:x1, 1:x3, 2:y2, 3:y4}, {0:x2, 1:x4, 2:y1, 3:y3},
    {0:x2, 1:x4, 2:y2, 3:y4}] 
    """
    qsorcs = []
    params = []
    #index representation of params, as cartesian product must respect fixed positions
    #of arguments and not their values, ie [x1, x3] vary together in example
    tempidxrep = []
    for key, value in input_params.items():
        qsorcs.append(key)
        params.append(value)
        tempidxrep.append([i for i in range(len(value))])

    idxrep = []
    #remove redundancy in index representation governed by fixed relationships in together
    for fix_rel in together:
        idxrep.append(tempidxrep[fix_rel[0]])

    #sweep combinations via carteisan product
    idxcombos = itertools.product(*idxrep)

    #reconstruct actual parameter combinations
    param_combos = []
    for idxcombo in idxcombos:
        trial = {qsorcs[j]: params[j][idxcombo[i]] for i in range(len(idxcombo)) for j in together[i]}
        param_combos.append(trial)

    return param_combos
```

Is there an easier and better way to do this with built in tools like itertools that can handle keys being integers or tuples without writing separate complicated functions? In other words, am I just approaching this seemingly simple problem from the wrong direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having posted this question, I wrote an improved version of the original code that allows for the original input (dictionary of the form `{h_n: hval}` with h an iteger representing nth qubit) along with the additional inputs of the form `{J_nm: Jval}` with J_nm a tuple (qn, qm) of the coupling strength between qubits n and m. In addition, it doesn't break when some qubits/ couplers are excluded form the "together" lits like the original did. Thus, this new code functionally works for what I want to do. Nevertheless, I suspect there is a better way out there.

```
def fixed_relationship_sweep(input_params, together):
"""
Inputs
------
input_params: {qorc1:[x1, x2], qorc2:[x3, x4], qorc3:[y1, y2], qorc4:[y3, y4]]}
dictionary mapping qubits or couplers to parameter lists to iterate through
together: [[qorc1, qorc2], [qorc3, qorc4]]
list of qubit lists that specify which qubit parameters to sweep with a fixed relationship

Output
------
fixed_rel_sweep: [{trial1}, {trial2}, ...{trialn}] where qubits labelled as "together" are
swept with fixed 1-1 relationship, ie, above produces:
[{qorc1:x1, qorc2:x3, qorc3:y1, qorc4:y3}, {qorc1:x1, qorc2:x3, qorc3:y2, qorc4:y4},
{qorc1:x2, qorc2:x4, qorc3:y1, qorc4:y3},{qorc1:x2, qorc2:x4, qorc3:y2, qorc4:y4}] 
"""
#list of qubits or couplers
qsorcs = []
#index representation of params, as cartesian product must respect fixed positions
#of arguments and not their values, ie [x1, x3] vary together in example
idxrep = {}
for key, value in input_params.items():
    qsorcs.append(key)
    idxrep[key] = [i for i in range(len(value))]

#remove redundancy in index representation governed by fixed relationships in together
count = 0
for fix_rel in together:
    for j in range(len(fix_rel)):
        if j != 0:
            del idxrep[fix_rel[j]]

#sweep combinations via cartesian product
idxdict_combos = (list(dict(zip(idxrep, x)) for x in itertools.product(*idxrep.values())))

#reconstruct actual parameter combinations with "redundant" parameter values
dict_combos = []
for combo in idxdict_combos:
    #add back in "redundant" parameters
    for fix_rel in together:
        for qorc in fix_rel[1::]:
            combo[qorc] = combo[fix_rel[0]]

    #add back in true values corresponding to indices
    tempdict = {}
    for key, value in combo.items():
        tempdict[key] = input_params[key][value]

    dict_combos.append(tempdict)

return dict_combos
```